# How to copy multiple element values from XML value into a table?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have following script, and I want to fill `AddOnFeatureEnum` values in `#rewardscusts` table :

```
    DECLARE @AddOnFeatures AS VARCHAR(1500)

    DECLARE @AddOnFeaturesXML AS XML

   SET @AddOnFeatures = 
    '<p1:Addons
xmlns:p1="http://www.alarm.com/WebServices"><p1:AddOnFeatureEnum>WeatherToPanel</p1:AddOnFeatureEnum><p1:AddOnFeatureEnum>EnterpriseNotices</p1:AddOnFeatureEnum></p1:Addons>'

SET @AddOnFeaturesXML = CAST(@AddOnFeatures AS XML)

SELECT @AddOnFeaturesXML

CREATE TABLE #rewardscusts (AddOnFeature VARCHAR(100) primary key)

-- I want to fill AddOnFeatureEnum values in #rewardscusts table please

DROP TABLE #rewardscusts
```

Comment: I found out how to format the XML in the question. Thank you for editing.:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible way by shredding the XML on `p1:AddOnFeatureEnum` elements (reference [`nodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) method for this part), then use `value()` method on the shredded elements to extract the `varchar(100)` values :

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.alarm.com/WebServices' as p1)
INSERT INTO #rewardscusts
SELECT enum.value('.','varchar(100)')
FROM @AddOnFeaturesXML.nodes('/p1:Addons/p1:AddOnFeatureEnum') as T(enum)
```

**[This is full working demo codes :](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/1530)**

```
DECLARE @AddOnFeatures AS VARCHAR(1500)
DECLARE @AddOnFeaturesXML AS XML

SET @AddOnFeatures = 
'<p1:Addons
xmlns:p1="http://www.alarm.com/WebServices"><p1:AddOnFeatureEnum>WeatherToPanel</p1:AddOnFeatureEnum><p1:AddOnFeatureEnum>EnterpriseNotices</p1:AddOnFeatureEnum></p1:Addons>'

SET @AddOnFeaturesXML = CAST(@AddOnFeatures AS XML)

DECLARE @rewardscusts TABLE(AddOnFeature VARCHAR(100) primary key)

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.alarm.com/WebServices' as p1)
INSERT INTO @rewardscusts
SELECT x.value('.','varchar(100)')
FROM @AddOnFeaturesXML.nodes('/p1:Addons/p1:AddOnFeatureEnum') as T(x)

SELECT * FROM @rewardscusts
```

**output :**

```
|      AddOnFeature |
|-------------------|
| EnterpriseNotices |
|    WeatherToPanel |
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. Where can I learn more about this topic please?

Comment: @PiyushVarma I learned SQL Server XQuery only form relevant MSDN pages, like [the one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) I posted in this answer. There are plenty example for various query scenario provided there, and you can search for many other scenario here in SO. You can also learn XPath separately, as it is an independent topic that is closely related to XQuery.

Comment: @PiyushVarma And again, please consider to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thank you very miuch. I clicked on the check box underneath 1 and it turned green. Is the green checkmark indication that I accepted the answer?

Comment: Exactly. You can read more in the link in my previous comment :)